# VSTO Outlook Addin - Move Selected emails to another Email Accounts

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

My goal is create VSTO Addin for Outlook, to help user sorting emails via Buttons in Custom Ribbon.

In custom Ribbon i have a button's. The button's are permanently set to a specific folder's in the main email inbox.

`Code:`

```
        private void btnMainInboxFolder_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
        Outlook.Selection selectedItems = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
        Outlook.Folder inboxFolder = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) as Outlook.Folder;
        Outlook.Folder trashEmailFolder = inboxFolder.Folders["Trash Emails"] as Outlook.Folder;

        foreach (object selectedItem in selectedItems)
        {
            if (selectedItem is Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
            {
                mailItem.Move(trashEmail);
            }
        }
    }
```

The Problem starts when i have several email accounts mapped in Outlook. When i Selected email from `Mail Account 1` how i target folder in inbox of `Mail Account 2` ?

thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple accounts configured in Outlook you may find the [NameSpace.Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property helpful. It returns a `Stores` collection object that represents all the `Store` objects in the current profile, for example:

```
private void EnumerateFoldersInDefaultStore()
{
    Outlook.Folder root =
        Application.Session.
        DefaultStore.GetRootFolder() as Outlook.Folder;
    EnumerateFolders(root);
}

// Uses recursion to enumerate Outlook subfolders.
private void EnumerateFolders(Outlook.Folder folder)
{
    Outlook.Folders childFolders =
        folder.Folders;
    if (childFolders.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Outlook.Folder childFolder in childFolders)
        {
            // Write the folder path.
            Debug.WriteLine(childFolder.FolderPath);
            // Call EnumerateFolders using childFolder.
            EnumerateFolders(childFolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can use the [GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method of the `Store` class to get any default folder in a specific store. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

> The Problem starts when i have several email accounts mapped in Outlook. When i Selected email from Mail Account 1 how i target folder in inbox of Mail Account 2 ?

Find the right store first and then get the target folder where you need to move items. You may also find the [NameSpace.Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.accounts) property which returns an `Accounts` collection object that represents all the `Account` objects in the current profile.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`, use `Store.GetDefaultFolder` (if you are navigating to the folder relative to a default folder) or get to it by its name/path using `Store.Folders` collection to drill down to the desired folder.

The target Store object can be retrieved (by name/index/etc.) from `Application.Session.Stores` collection.

Comment: oki, but what is correct syntax for path to folder in second mailbox ? for example "\\\\365@user.onmicrosoft.com\\Index\\Tresh Emails"

Comment: You can get folder path from the folder (`MAPIFolder.FullFolderPath`), but you cannot get a folder given its path (unless you se Redemption and its `RDOSession.GetFolderFromPath`). I meant building the folder path in your code: `Application.Session.Stores["365@user.onmicrosoft.com"].Folders["Index"].Folders["Tresh Emails"]`